# Winter 22 Sandbox permission error

Tags: permissions, sandbox, release, winter22

In our testing Sandbox environment, now on "Winter 22 Patch 3.2", we have started getting this error for non-admin users viewing account pages:

> Looks like there's a problem.
> Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID shown here and any other related details.
> Error ID: 27823921-30595 (1902414912)

We've set up debug logs for affected users and reproduced the error, however, no errors show up in the produced debug logs. We suspect this is a permission issue related to the new Winter sandbox release but so far have not been able to find the source of the error.

Using the network inspector, we found more info about the gack:

```
"org.auraframework.throwable.AuraRuntimeException: ui.services.exceptions.ServiceException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: flexipage.common.api.component.designtimeinfo.throwable.DesignTimeInfoRuntimeException: Could not decode value [@@@sfdc=0Wg3p000000TN28=sfdc@@@] for component [lbpm:actionList] attribute [recordActionDeployment] type [RecordActionDeployment]
    at ui.flexipage.components.raptor.page.GeneratedPageModuleBuilder.getDefinition(GeneratedPageModuleBuilder.java:426)
    at ui.forcegenerated.components.services.GeneratedModuleServiceCollectionImpl.getDefinition(GeneratedModuleServiceCollectionImpl.java:53)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5555.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy692.getDefinition(Unknown Source)
    at ui.forcegenerated.components.services.GeneratedModuleDefRegistry.getDef(GeneratedModuleDefRegistry.java:37)
    at ui.forcegenerated.components.services.GeneratedModuleDefRegistry$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$656566af.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at ui.forcegenerated.components.services.GeneratedModuleDefRegistry$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9b820f1e.getDef(<generated>)
    at org.auraframework.impl.linker.AuraLinker.fillLinkingDefinition(AuraLinker.java:559)
    at org.auraframework.impl.linker.AuraLinker.getHelper(AuraLinker.java:318)
    at org.auraframework.impl.linker.AuraLinker.getDefinitionDuringLink(AuraLinker.java:195)
    at org.auraframework.impl.DefinitionServiceImpl.getDefinition(DefinitionServiceImpl.java:439)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4005.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy249.getDefinition(Unknown Source)
    at ui.force.impl.aura.raptor.resolver.ModuleInstanceHelper$1.computeValue(ModuleInstanceHelper.java:84)
    at ui.force.impl.aura.raptor.resolver.ModuleInstanceHelper$1.computeValue(ModuleInstanceHelper.java:1)
    at ui.services.cache.AbstractTimeoutBasedCacheValueProvider.getNewValue(AbstractTimeoutBasedCacheValueProvider.java:42)
    at ui.services.internal.cache.CacheImpl.doGet(CacheImpl.java:82)
    at ui.services.internal.cache.PermsetAwareCache.get(PermsetAwareCache.java:66)
    at ui.services.internal.util.CacheUtilImpl.getFromCacheLocalOnly(CacheUtilImpl.java:238)
    at ui.force.impl.aura.raptor.resolver.ModuleInstanceHelper.getFromCache(ModuleInstanceHelper.java:73)
    at ui.force.impl.aura.raptor.resolver.ModuleInstanceHelper.resolve(ModuleInstanceHelper.java:144)
    at ui.force.impl.aura.raptor.generation.AdgRollupGeneratedModuleServiceImpl.getModuleDef(AdgRollupGeneratedModuleServiceImpl.java:226)
    at ui.force.impl.aura.raptor.generation.AdgRollupGeneratedModuleServiceImpl.getDefinition(AdgRollupGeneratedModuleServiceImpl.java:167)
    at ui.forcegenerated.components.services.GeneratedModuleServiceCollectionImpl.getDefinition(GeneratedModuleServiceCollectionImpl.java:53)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5555.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy692.getDefinition(Unknown Source)
    at ui.forcegenerated.components.services.GeneratedModuleDefRegistry.getDef(GeneratedModuleDefRegistry.java:37)
    at ui.forcegenerated.components.services.GeneratedModuleDefRegistry$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$656566af.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at ui.forcegenerated.components.services.GeneratedModuleDefRegistry$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9b820f1e.getDef(<generated>)
    at org.auraframework.impl.linker.AuraLinker.fillLinkingDefinition(AuraLinker.java:559)
    at org.auraframework.impl.linker.AuraLinker.getHelper(AuraLinker.java:318)
    at org.auraframework.impl.linker.AuraLinker.linkDefinition(AuraLinker.java:168)
    at org.auraframework.impl.DefinitionServiceImpl.compileDependencyEntry(DefinitionServiceImpl.java:1307)
    at org.auraframework.impl.DefinitionServiceImpl.getDefinition(DefinitionServiceImpl.java:453)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4005.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy249.getDefinition(Unknown Source)
    at ui.force.impl.aura.raptor.resolver.ModuleInstanceHelper$1.computeValue(ModuleInstanceHelper.java:84)
    at ui.force.impl.aura.raptor.resolver.ModuleInstanceHelper$1.computeValue(ModuleInstanceHelper.java:1)
    at ui.services.cache.AbstractTimeoutBasedCacheValueProvider.getNewValue(AbstractTimeoutBasedCacheValueProvider.java:42)
    at ui.services.internal.cache.CacheImpl.doGet(CacheImpl.java:82)
    at ui.services.internal.cache.PermsetAwareCache.get(PermsetAwareCache.java:66)
    at ui.services.internal.util.CacheUtilImpl.getFromCacheLocalOnly(CacheUtilImpl.java:238)
    at ui.force.impl.aura.raptor.resolver.ModuleInstanceHelper.getFromCache(ModuleInstanceHelper.java:73)
    at ui.force.impl.aura.raptor.resolver.ModuleInstanceHelper.resolve(ModuleInstanceHelper.java:144)
    at ui.force.impl.aura.raptor.resolver.AbstractTemplateModuleResourceResolver.resolve(AbstractTemplateModuleResourceResolver.java:52)
    at ui.force.impl.aura.raptor.dependency.TemplateModuleServiceImpl.resolveReference(TemplateModuleServiceImpl.java:70)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5574.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1285.resolveReference(Unknown Source)
    at ui.force.impl.aura.raptor.resolver.TemplateResolverServiceImpl.getResolvedTemplateModuleBundles(TemplateResolverServiceImpl.java:185)
    at ui.force.impl.aura.raptor.resolver.TemplateResolverServiceImpl.resolveTemplates(TemplateResolverServiceImpl.java:74)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5573.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy812.resolveTemplates(Unknown Source)
    at ui.force.components.controllers.global.DynamicComponentController.getTemplateDescriptorWithExpansionBundle(DynamicComponentController.java:118)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7175.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.auraframework.impl.java.controller.JavaAction.run(JavaAction.java:170)
    at org.auraframework.impl.ServerServiceImpl.run(ServerServiceImpl.java:206)
    at org.auraframework.impl.ServerServiceImpl.run(ServerServiceImpl.java:268)
    at org.auraframework.http.AuraServlet.handleActionRequest(AuraServlet.java:862)
    at org.auraframework.http.AuraServlet.doPost(AuraServlet.java:968)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:755)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1632)
    at system.filter.AuraDomainRedirectFilter.doFilter(AuraDomainRedirectFilter.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at aura.impl.http.SFDCAuraContextFilter.doFilter(SFDCAuraContextFilter.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at sfdc.commons.filters.useragent.CommonUserAgentRewriteFilter.doFilter(CommonUserAgentRewriteFilter.java:27)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at klein.filter.JettyStreamWriterAdaptorFilter.doFilter(JettyStreamWriterAdaptorFilter.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at sfdc.commons.filters.cookie.CookieCatalogFilter.doFilter(CookieCatalogFilter.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at sfdc.commons.filters.vulnerability.CommonVulnerabilityCheckFilter.doFilter(CommonVulnerabilityCheckFilter.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at system.filter.SeparateDomainRedirectFilter.doFilter(SeparateDomainRedirectFilter.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at core.dns.filter.CustomDomainMappingFilter.doFilter(CustomDomainMappingFilter.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at core.dns.filter.SiteRedirectMappingFilter.doFilter(SiteRedirectMappingFilter.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at core.dns.filter.BandwidthMeterFilter.doFilter(BandwidthMeterFilter.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at system.filter.OrgDomainFilter.doFilter(OrgDomainFilter.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at system.filter.StatsOnlyFilter.doFilter(StatsOnlyFilter.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at system.filter.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at sfdc.commons.filters.modifyparam.ModifiableParameterFilter.doFilter(ModifiableParameterFilter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at klein9425.filter.MultiPartFilter.doFilter(MultiPartFilter.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at system.filter.BasePreGzipFilter.doFilter(BasePreGzipFilter.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at com.force.http.routing.RoutingFilter.doFilter(RoutingFilter.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at system.filter.InstanceRedirectFilter.doFilter(InstanceRedirectFilter.java:773)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at sfdc.commons.filters.routing.CommonRemoteAddrFilter.doFilter(CommonRemoteAddrFilter.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at system.filter.LegacyJSPFilter.doFilter(LegacyJSPFilter.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at routing.ios.IosRoutingFilter.doFilter(IosRoutingFilter.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at core.feeds.notification.tracking.ClickTrackingFilter.doFilter(ClickTrackingFilter.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at core.dns.filter.SitesRuntimeForwardingFilter.requestIsNotForSites(SitesRuntimeForwardingFilter.java:344)
    at core.dns.filter.SitesRuntimeForwardingFilter.doFilterInternal(SitesRuntimeForwardingFilter.java:590)
    at core.dns.filter.SitesRuntimeForwardingFilter.doFilter(SitesRuntimeForwardingFilter.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at sites.gateway.EdgeGatewayCachingFilter.doFilter(EdgeGatewayCachingFilter.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at sites.gateway.EdgeGatewayFilter.doFilter(EdgeGatewayFilter.java:27)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at sites.gateway.InstanceProxyFilter.doFilter(InstanceProxyFilter.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at routing.filter.LoadBalancerFilter.doFilter(LoadBalancerFilter.java:84)
    at routing.loadbalancer.SfdcLoadBalancerFilter.doFilter(SfdcLoadBalancerFilter.java:782)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at common.util.database.ZeroDowntimeSpinModeFilter.doFilter(ZeroDowntimeSpinModeFilter.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at system.orgdomain.OrgDomainLoadBalancerFilter.handleLocally(OrgDomainLoadBalancerFilter.java:169)
    at system.orgdomain.OrgDomainLoadBalancerFilter.doFilter(OrgDomainLoadBalancerFilter.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at system.filter.MeshDistributedTracingFilter.doFilter(MeshDistributedTracingFilter.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at system.filter.MeshDynamicRequestRoutingFilter.doFilter(MeshDynamicRequestRoutingFilter.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at sfdc.commons.filters.context.CommonStackableContextWatchingFilter.doFilter(CommonStackableContextWatchingFilter.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at sfdc.commons.filters.context.CommonContextReleaseFilter.doFilter(CommonContextReleaseFilter.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at system.filter.SessionNeverEstablishedLogFilter.doFilter(SessionNeverEstablishedLogFilter.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at com.force.http.routing.RoutingFilter.doFilter(RoutingFilter.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at com.force.http.routing.RoutingFilter.handleFilter(RoutingFilter.java:140)
    at com.force.http.routing.RoutingFilter.doFilter(RoutingFilter.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at system.filter.HttpsRedirectFilter.doFilter(HttpsRedirectFilter.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at sfdc.commons.filters.security.CommonResponseHeaderFilter.doFilter(CommonResponseHeaderFilter.java:49)
    at system.filter.ResponseHeaderFilter.doFilter(ResponseHeaderFilter.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at sfdc.commons.filters.headers.CommonJettyResponseHeadersCustomizerFilter.doFilter(CommonJettyResponseHeadersCustomizerFilter.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at sfdc.commons.filters.buffer.CommonResponseBufferSizeAdjusterFilter.doFilter(CommonResponseBufferSizeAdjusterFilter.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at klein9425.filter.IncludableResponseWrapperFilter.doFilter(IncludableResponseWrapperFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at system.filter.cookie.CookieProcessorFilter.doFilter(CookieProcessorFilter.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at sfdc.commons.filters.logging.CommonAccessLogFilter.doFilter(CommonAccessLogFilter.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at sfdc.commons.filters.context.CommonRequestIdFilter.doFilter(CommonRequestIdFilter.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at system.filter.RegulatorWaitTestFilter.doFilter(RegulatorWaitTestFilter.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at system.filter.RegulatorFilter.doFilter(RegulatorFilter.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at system.filter.RequestPathSecurityFilter.doFilter(RequestPathSecurityFilter.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at sfdc.commons.filters.encoding.CommonRequestEncodingFilter.doFilter(CommonRequestEncodingFilter.java:86)
    at system.filter.RequestEncodingFilter.doFilter(RequestEncodingFilter.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1619)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:767)
    at klein9425.handler.SfdcGzipHandler.handle(SfdcGzipHandler.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1607)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.server.handler.BufferedResponseHandler.handle(BufferedResponseHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1297)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at klein9425.jetty9425.RegexServletHandler.doScope(RegexServletHandler.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.jetty9425.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: ui.services.exceptions.ServiceException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: flexipage.common.api.component.designtimeinfo.throwable.DesignTimeInfoRuntimeException: Could not decode value [@@@sfdc=0Wg3p000000TN28=sfdc@@@] for component [lbpm:actionList] attribute [recordActionDeployment] type [RecordActionDeployment]
    at ui.flexipage.impl.loader.FlexipageLoaderImpl.getCustomFlexipage(FlexipageLoaderImpl.java:129)
    at ui.flexipage.impl.loader.FlexipageLoaderImpl.loadFlexipage(FlexipageLoaderImpl.java:70)
    at ui.flexipage.impl.FlexipageRuntimeImpl.describeFlexipage(FlexipageRuntimeImpl.java:122)
    at ui.flexipage.impl.FlexipageRuntimeImpl.getFlexipageInfo(FlexipageRuntimeImpl.java:102)
    at ui.flexipage.components.raptor.page.GeneratedPageModuleBuilder.buildPage(GeneratedPageModuleBuilder.java:463)
    at ui.flexipage.components.raptor.page.GeneratedPageModuleBuilder.getDefinition(GeneratedPageModuleBuilder.java:394)
    ... 235 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: flexipage.common.api.component.designtimeinfo.throwable.DesignTimeInfoRuntimeException: Could not decode value [@@@sfdc=0Wg3p000000TN28=sfdc@@@] for component [lbpm:actionList] attribute [recordActionDeployment] type [RecordActionDeployment]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999)
    at ui.flexipage.impl.loader.FlexipageLoaderImpl.getCustomFlexipage(FlexipageLoaderImpl.java:121)
    ... 240 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: flexipage.common.api.component.designtimeinfo.throwable.DesignTimeInfoRuntimeException: Could not decode value [@@@sfdc=0Wg3p000000TN28=sfdc@@@] for component [lbpm:actionList] attribute [recordActionDeployment] type [RecordActionDeployment]
    at flexipage.impl.service.CoreCustomFlexipageServiceImpl.getFlexipage(CoreCustomFlexipageServiceImpl.java:179)
    at flexipage.impl.service.CustomFlexipageServiceImpl.getFlexipage(CustomFlexipageServiceImpl.java:37)
    at ui.flexipage.impl.loader.FlexipageLoaderImpl.getCustomFlexipage(FlexipageLoaderImpl.java:120)
    ... 240 more
Caused by: flexipage.common.api.component.designtimeinfo.throwable.DesignTimeInfoRuntimeException: Could not decode value [@@@sfdc=0Wg3p000000TN28=sfdc@@@] for component [lbpm:actionList] attribute [recordActionDeployment] type [RecordActionDeployment]
    at flexipage.common.impl.attributetype.DesignTimeAttributeTypeInfoServiceImpl.decodeAttributeValue(DesignTimeAttributeTypeInfoServiceImpl.java:247)
    at flexipage.common.impl.attributetype.DesignTimeAttributeTypeInfoServiceImpl.decodeAttributeValue(DesignTimeAttributeTypeInfoServiceImpl.java:154)
    at flexipage.common.impl.attributetype.DesignTimeAttributeTypeInfoServiceImpl.decodeAttributeValue(DesignTimeAttributeTypeInfoServiceImpl.java:1)
    at flexipage.impl.service.CoreCustomFlexipageServiceImpl.getAttributeValue(CoreCustomFlexipageServiceImpl.java:839)
    at flexipage.impl.service.CoreCustomFlexipageServiceImpl.getProperties(CoreCustomFlexipageServiceImpl.java:318)
    at flexipage.impl.service.CoreCustomFlexipageServiceImpl.processRegion(CoreCustomFlexipageServiceImpl.java:668)
    at flexipage.impl.service.CoreCustomFlexipageServiceImpl.getRegionsInstancesProperties(CoreCustomFlexipageServiceImpl.java:509)
    at flexipage.impl.service.CoreCustomFlexipageServiceImpl.getFlexiPage(CoreCustomFlexipageServiceImpl.java:247)
    at flexipage.impl.service.CoreCustomFlexipageServiceImpl.getFlexipage(CoreCustomFlexipageServiceImpl.java:162)
    ... 242 more
Caused by: flexipage.common.attributetype.exceptions.AttributeValidationException: Something went wrong when we ran a query for deployment 0Wg3p000000TN28. Refresh the page and try again.
    at flexipage.common.attributetype.RecordActionDeploymentAttributeType.getDeploymentDevNameFromId(RecordActionDeploymentAttributeType.java:144)
    at flexipage.common.attributetype.RecordActionDeploymentAttributeType.decodeReferences(RecordActionDeploymentAttributeType.java:84)
    at flexipage.common.impl.attributetype.DesignTimeAttributeTypeInfoImpl.decodeReferences(DesignTimeAttributeTypeInfoImpl.java:203)
    at flexipage.common.impl.attributetype.DesignTimeAttributeTypeInfoServiceImpl.decodeAttributeValue(DesignTimeAttributeTypeInfoServiceImpl.java:243)
    ... 250 more
"
```

Comment: If you don't get any responses here, I'd make a case with Salesforce Support.  I'd also recommend posting on the Release Readiness Trailblazers group: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/groups/0F9300000001okuCAA?lang=en&tab=discussion

Comment: there's an internal bug for this gack. Out of curiosity, do you have the Actions & Recommendations component on the account page?

Comment: We do, yes @KrisGoncalves. However removing that component from the flexipage didn't seem to remove the gack.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves Is there anything we can do to resolve the error before your team fixes the bug? It's blocking all of our training

Comment: And you're able to go into `Setup --> Actions & Recommendations` and click `edit` on the deployment with no issues? I'm not on that team so just peeking at their work - I'll let you know if any major update comes through on a workaround. In the meantime, I would definitely recommend putting in a case (with relevant high priority). You can reference Work ID: W-9809281

Comment: We don't have a recent Actions & Recommendations deployment. I was able to edit one from January and it popped up the modal and I'm able to click all the way through to the "Save" button

Comment: if you give the affected users the `View DeveloperName` permission (under `General User Permissions`) for their profile, does the error go away?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves that appears to work to let member profiles load, yes. Is this something we need to change moving forward, or is this just a hack fix as a workaround until the bug is fixed? The answer to that affects whether or not we commit the change to source control

Comment: It's looking like it might be an expected change moving forward. [RecordActionDeployment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_recordactiondeployment.htm) is called out in Winter '22 [release notes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000362829&type=1) as enforcing this new access requirement, but I'll put an answer in when I'm certain.

Answer (score 2):

For users running into this error on custom profiles, **you will have to enable the new permission** introduced in Winter '22 called `View DeveloperName` in your sandbox.

This is mentioned in [Grant Access to the DeveloperName Field to Users Who Required It](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_permissions_grant_access_developername_field.htm&type=5&release=234). Standard profiles (with Salesforce User License) will have this enabled for them with the release (as they have been in sandboxes). In production, when the release goes live,  you'll have to enable this permission for your existing, custom profiles if you're running into issues

*I'll try to update this answer if anything changes from now until the release with patches*.

---

*Longer explanation*:

Winter '22 has introduced a new permission called [ViewDeveloperName](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000362829&type=1).

> **How does this change impact my org?**
>
> Following the Winter ’22 release,
> some users may lose access to the DeveloperName field on objects they
> typically interact with. If necessary, restore access by granting
> permission to these users with the procedure outlined in the next
> section.
>
> **What do I need to do?**
>
> To grant explicit access to view,
> group, sort, and filter the DeveloperName field for affected API
> objects and types, give users the View Setup and Configuration OR View
> DeveloperName permission via a profile or permission set.

Your error is specifically related to [RecordActionDeployment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_recordactiondeployment.htm) which is related to the configuration settings for Actions & Recommendations. It's also listed on the list of types that enforce this new restriction with Winter '22. You may see this error on a different object than what you listed (Account), but the error will be similar.

For custom profiles, you'll have to give the users 'View DeveloperName` access (which gives no other access) to fix the issue in Winter '22. For standard profiles, they'll be updated with this permission by the release. You are able to solely enable this permission (no other dependent permission is tied to it).

You can see a list of objects enforcing this permission in [New Permission Requirements for DeveloperName Field](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000362829&type=1)

Comment: Thanks for the assist, it's stressful and painful that we experienced a full outage of our training environment while prepping hundreds of agents to onboard thousands of new users, and that the only way we were able to get help was the random luck that a SF employee checked a stackoverflow question, not even on that team, especially right after the 5th global SF DNS outage. I wish there were better channels, better error messages, and real release notes, not retroactive "knowledge base" articles that aren't discoverable.

Comment: This permission doesn't exist outside of sandboxes, so what are developers supposed to do? We can't commit this to our codebase because then we can't deploy to production.

Comment: I agree that the channels aren't as good as they could be when I was on the other side, though I think it has been getting better and am partial to this community! In terms of this issue, I wouldn't commit this change until after production go-live for the Winter '22 release. It'll have to be a post-Salesforce release deployment. You'll have to make this change to any sandbox you rely on that is in preview (on Winter '22) manually for the time being, it seems.

Comment: @AndyRay - If you're on Winter '22 Patch 5, you can test whether removing this permission for those users' profiles no longer causes the error. I believe they may have patched this behavior so it doesn't throw an error in this specific scenario (for `RecordActionDeployment`)

Answer (score 0):

We have also faced the same issue . Users were not able to view Campaigns in Classic Mode.

After raising a case with Salesforce , we got to know about the new implementation where a few objects can be impacted .

Below is the KA :

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000362829&type=1